# Inappbrowser cordova plugin deployment issue

Tags: angular, deployment, configuration, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using angular14 , cordova 11.0.0 and ios 6.2.0, I installed Inappbrowser cordova plugin then builded and it works perfcetly on my local application.
Afterward , I deployed it using Jenkins but the plugin dosen't work on the deployed version, i took the deployed project folder and tested it on xcode , it shows this error :

typeerror: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cordova.inappbrowser.open')

knowing that the installation and configuration is the same as the local one.

I tried :

- removing and installing inappbrowser plugin\IOS platform\cordova and build afterward
- building before and after updating the plugin
- added `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />` and `<feature name="InAppBrowser"><param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" /></feature>` in config.xml
- removed the same configuration
  _ used `deviceReady = fromEvent(document, 'deviceready');` to `cordova.inappbrowser.open`use in it

none of that worked